# ¿Por qué al guardar el contenido alfanumérico de un TMemo en una BD, desde Delphi, este se guarda en números?

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

Agradeciendo de antemano sus orientaciones.

Al guardar en BD el contenido de varios TMEMO estos se guardan de forma numérica.

```
procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin                      
  VPROY_PLAZOS.AsString:=Memo1.Lines; 
  VPROY_DESARROLLO:=Memo2.Lines;
  VPROY_CORRECCIONES:=Memo3.Lines;
  VPROY_SEGUIMIENTO:=Memo4.Lines;
  VPROY_AUDITORIA:=Memo5.Lines;
  VPROY_COMENTARIOS:=Memo6.Lines; 
  VPROY_CHAT:=Memo7.Lines;
end;
```

EN BD todos los datos son VARCHAR y al ejecutar la consulta SQL en estos campos solo me muestra números.

Por ejemplo: El Memo2 debería mostrar lo siguiente al ejecutar la consulta SQL "El contenido debe ser inédito, elaborado por primera y única vez para el cliente"

El resultado que arroja es el siguiente: 172231376.

Según entiendo lo guarda de forma numérica.

He intentado buscar solucionar con funciones que me permitan convertir este numero a string. Pero no tengo claridad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si pones **memo1.lines** lo que obtienes es el **objeto TLines** donde está el contenido del **memo**. Al guardar eso, seguramente estás guardando la dirección de memoria donde reside ese objeto (recuerda que los objetos son punteros), es decir, por eso guardas un número, lo que debes asignar es la **propiedad Text**, que tiene el texto como tal:

```
Memo1.Lines.Text
```

De esta forma si guardas el texto del **memo**.

Comment: O directamente añadir  Memo1.Text  (que también funciona).